# Flowtype: dynamically extending classes

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is it possible to manually define additional methods for an existing class?

My specific usecase is bluebird's `promisifyAll()` which:

> Promisifies the entire object by going through the object's properties and creating an async equivalent of each function on the object and its prototype chain… http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html

Obviously, flow wouldn't be able to figure this out automatically. So, I'm willing to help it. The question is HOW?

Consider the following code

```
import http from 'http'
import { promisifyAll } from 'bluebird'

promisifyAll(http)

const server = http.createServer(() => { console.log('request is in'); })
server.listenAsync(8080).then(() => {
  console.log('Server is ready to handle connections')
})
```

Flow gives the following error here:

```
property `listenAsync`. Property not found in
Server
```

There wouldn't be any error if I used `listen`. flow's smart enough to see that this is a real method defined in a module. But `listenAsync` is a dynamic addition by `promisifyAll` and is invisible to flow

Answer (score 7):

That's not possible and that would not be really safe to do. Here is something you can do for your case:

first declare `bluebird` as following:

```
declare module "bluebird" {
  declare function promisifyAll(arg: any): any
}
```

Then do this:

```
import httpNode from 'http'
import { promisifyAll } from 'bluebird'
import type { Server } from 'http'


type PromisifiedServer = Server & {
  listenAsync(port: number, hostname?: string, backlog?: number): Promise<PromisifiedServer>;
};

type PromisifiedHttp = {
  createServer(listener: Function): PromisifiedServer;
};

const http: PromisifiedHttp = promisifyAll(httpNode)
```

Here we manually cast `http` to type `PromisifiedHttp`. We still have to declare all promisifed types manually, although we can use type intersection to extends existing types.

Comment: thanks. this one is not perfect, as it requires code change. minor change, but still. and it means that code would have to be changed for other dynamic cases too. I understand "would not really be safe" part, but it's not realistic as in both cases compiler can not infer data from code and trusts me to write the correct definition.

Comment: in general it's not possible to express some dynamic patterns in flow. You have to isolate too dynamic parts from flow and provide appropriate declarations for typed parts

Comment: It would lessen the curve dramatically if flow had a mechanism for doing things like prototype extension in an "unsafe" way.  For instance, if I use a library like should.js or chai, I should be able to create an interface in libs that extends Object's prototype with the 'should' function. If this could not be done in a type safe way, allow the consumer to disable static analysis on those code paths that use it instead of throwing errors.